# android install failure - "cmd: Can't find service: package" (not emulator)

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to test some apks on a HiKey 960 with Android (AOSP), but whenever I try to install any apk I get:
`adb: failed to install whatever.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package`
This is with either
`adb install -t whatever.apk`
or through Android Studio 4.0
Almost all searches for this error suggest I cold boot my emulator, but I'm not using an emulator...
The only non-emulator result came up with it being a lack of space, but the HiKey is virtually empty, and has 3.3GB free, and my various trial apks are relatively small.
Has anyone struck this error before without an emulator, and have any ideas on what the problem might be? I'd like to avoid re-installing my whole HiKey if I can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From feedback elsewhere I eventually found someone who'd had the same problem. The 'package' service doesn't startup when booted, and the only fix was to re-image the HiKey device.
So that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Redmi Note 4 and after rebooting phone the error was gone.